# Why is my background image not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-deployment

I been trying to solve this for a few days now. My background image isn't showing but the image size (blank space) does.
Here is my code
HTML

```
<div id="contact">
<p>Let talk! contact us via e-mail, phone or text coming soon</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#contact{
 background-image: url("C:\Users\omar\Pictures\notaryweb/redphone.JPG");
width: 100%;
height: 105%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Also not sure if this matters but I have

```
body{
background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

in the beginning of my css sheet, and the background image is in the "body".
Thanks in advance for all your help, very detail answers are preferred.

Comment: Make sure that the image exist at the given path.

Comment: Use `background-image: url("C:\\Users\\omar\\Pictures\\notaryweb\\redphone.JPG");`. Because of escape characters your string is changed into `C:sersmaricturesotaryweb/redphone.JPG` which is not valid.

Comment: where is path html code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things........ 1st thing changing the image location and save where you save your html file ...
2nd thing

```
#contact{
 background-image: url("C:\Users\omar\Pictures\notaryweb\redphone.JPG");
width: 100%;
height: 105%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

use this your mistake is you use forward slash it will be backward slash..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `file:///` in your path. like below

```
background-image: url("file:///C:/Users/omar/Pictures/notaryweb/redphone.JPG");
```

Also, make sure file do exist.

Answer (score 0):

you are making slash mistake please put back slash "\"

wrong:
url("C:\Users\omar\Pictures\notaryweb/redphone.JPG")

correct:
url("C:\Users\omar\Pictures\notaryweb\redphone.JPG")

and make sure you have picture available on this path.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a better practice to keep your images in the context path of your web. Better to create an images folder in your web and use it. Doing so, will also not require you to replace your forward slashes with backward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

You should change C:\Users\omar\Pictures\notaryweb/redphone.JPG to C:\Users\omar\Pictures\notaryweb\redphone.JPG.

Also you should change `height: 105%` from percentage to `height: 105px`.